# How do you set up a second Network Interface Card to connect to a network printer?

Tags: networking, printing

I have an Ubuntu 15.04 box with a nic cabled to my router-modem for the internet.

Now I'd like to install and set up a second nic with the only task of connecting to my printer (apple laserwriter w/ network adapter).

How do I do this w/o causing conflicts?

Any special routing or subnet masking involved?

I was thinking two completely different private addresses with no subnetting.

eth0 (for internet) at the moment DHCP but I could make it static like this:

```
addr 192.168.x.x
subnet 255.255.255.0
default gateway 192.168.x.1
```

eth1 (to the printer's network adapter):

```
addr 172.16.x.x
subnet 255.255.255.0
no default gateway specified
```

Would something like this work or do I need a different solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make topology like this

```
|------|
|  PC  |=========|--------|      |--------|
|------|         | switch |======| router |
                 |--------|      |--------|
                    |
|---------|         |
| printer |=========|
|---------|
```

Connect `PC`, `printer` and `router` on the same `switch` 
Then configure you `PC` on this way

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

make conf on this way

```
auto eth1 
    iface eth1 inet static
           address 192.168.x.x
           netmask 255.255.255.0
           gateway 192.168.x.1
           up ip addr add 172.16.x.x/24 dev eth1 label eth1:1
```

Every thing will work and you will have only one noc card on `PC`.

Solution 2

Like you say, you can add nic to `PC` and configure second card `eth1` without `gw` and connect to `printer`. This solution aslo will work.

Solution 3

Simple connect `printer` to `switch port` on `router` and configure `printer` on the same network like `PC` but without `gw`. `PC` will communicate with `printer` through `router`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want only your pc to have access to the printer,
and that you can configure the printer to have a fixed IP address `172.16.x.y` this can work.

Otherwise you may need to setup a dhcp server for eth1 for the printer. `dnsmasq` is an easy choice.  But as the other answer says, why not put the printer on your router?

Comment: @2707974
I'd prefer to use two nics. But with two independent networks I'd have to reconfigure both the printer and another pc with 2 OSs on it. 
Not much of a sweat, but... 
what about creating 2 subnets, after all?
What would that be like?
Everything is in 
192.168.1.x

Comment: Could a simple static route be the solution?
Since my box is not part of a LAN and this is my config:
    my addr: 192.168.1.15 
    router: 182.168.1.1 from eth0
    printer: 182.168.1.100 from eth1

Could I just add this command

    route add -net 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth1

or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: You can do `route add -host 192.168.1.100 dev eth1` to get to the printer from
your pc.  What about your other pcs?

Comment: I'm going to connect to a switch connected to the printer. And the other PCs are connected to the switch too. Thanks!